# Python: replace a string by a float in txt file

Tags: python, string, replace, text-files

Here is a problem.

I have a .py file and a .txt.
To simplify, my .txt looks like:

```
@x@
```

In the .py I have

```
x=15
```

I would like to replace @x@ in the txt by the value saved in the py, ie my txt should look like

```
15
```

I tried with this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('mytxtfile.txt', inplace = 1)):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('@x@', 'x'))
```

or with

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('mytxtfile.txt', inplace = 1)):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('@x@', 'str(x)'))
```

The problem is that the "replace" method seems to consider only strings and I need to evaluate the value of the string.
Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just leave the quotes off `str(x)`

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('mytxtfile.txt', inplace = 1)): 
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('@x@', str(x)))
```

If you want more control over the output you can use a format string. Eg for 2 decimal places

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('mytxtfile.txt', inplace = 1)): 
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('@x@', "%.2f"%x))
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tested it but was not using the good txt file since it had been changed from my previous try with quotes, so it didnt work :(

Comment: @remi: "not using the good txt file since it had been changed from my previous try with quotes"?  What?

Comment: @S.Lott He had already run his incorrect code, replacing `'@x@'` with `'str(x)'`, so then when he tried to run the correct version (ie without the quotes around `str(x)`), it didn't work, because there weren't any `@x@`s in the input text file any more. That's how it reads to me, anyway.

Comment: @Cam Jackson: Guessing about their meaning is can be a bad policy.  When it's confusing, I prefer to ask for clarification.  I find it helpful because I learn more.

Answer (score 9):

The `string.Template` class is a good way to do this.

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings

```
from string import Template
class MyTemplate( Template ): 
    delimiter= '@'
    pattern= r"@(?P<escaped>@)|@(?P<named>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)@|@(?P<braced>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)@|@(?P<invalid>)"
```

Given this class definition, you can now do this

```
with open( 'a.txt', 'r' ) as source:
    t = MyTemplate(source.read())
    result= t.substitute( x=15 )
    print result
```

This allows you to use any number of substitutions anywhere in the template of almost any complexity.  This handles a very, very large number of cases gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you need to replace only 'x' or there are other variables in your files, but if so than i think you can also use the following code too:

```
# preparing dict based on a.py
d1 = {}
for line in open('a.py','r'):
    if line.strip() and '=' in line:
        k,v = line.strip().split('=')
        d1['@' + k + '@'] = v

# preparing data from a.txt using dict from a.py
res = ''
for line in open('a.txt','r'):# lines below can be optimized depending on what you really need
    for k,v in d1.items():
        if k in line:
            line.replace(k, v)
    res += line '\n'

# write modified data
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write(res.rstrip('\n'))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already received nice answers to your problem, there is an alternative way. Use python formatting strings in your text files (e.g. `%(x)f` or `%(x)s`). This example shows how it works:

```
line = '%(x)f or %(x).2f or %(x)s'
x = 15
print line % locals()
```

You can use a dictionary (e.g. `print line % {'x': 15}`) instead of locals(). I use it as a quick and dirty way to implement templates in python.